# dynamically added CSS link causes MIME type mismatch error IE9 only

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, mime-types

I'm trying to dynamically load a css file into the head of an iframe being added to a page. The following works correctly in every browser tested except for IE9 (FF, Chrome, IE8, 10 and 11 work fine). In IE9, I get "SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch", even the the link type is spec'd as 'text/css'

```
  var ss = document.createElement("link");
  ss.type = "text/css";
  ss.rel = "stylesheet";
  ss.href = "http://xxx.xxxxxxxx.com/request/component?name=sidebarflexone_css";
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ss);
```

The link appears to be rendered correctly to the page:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://xxx.xxxxxxxx.com/request/component?name=sidebarflexone_css">
```

Anyone know how I can workaround this?

Two things, I know there's better ways to do this, but I'm calling the css from a CMS so I'm limited there; and I'm not looking for a server side fix or regedit tweak, I need it to work out of the box for all (IE9 included) users.

Comment: have you set also a mime type in headers of the file you called like `header('Content-type: text/css');` ? i talk about the php parts of the file requested via $_GET

Comment: I didn't, since its just a straight up text field for markup, no header options for calling the file itself.

Comment: you should add the content-type since the link file has no .css extension. I had this very same problem with firefox long ago , where css was loaded as plain text and not used as CSS as i expected. It won't hurt anyway :)

Comment: component?name=sidebarflexone_css tells me that your CMS checks the name value and then includes the file that matches. This where content-type should be added, before the include() (or prepend or else method used in the script)

Comment: Actually changing the component name to include .css did the trick, but I will see if i can somehow add a contenttype to include with the paramaters (seems cleaner). Thanks!

Comment: And does this happen only when the `<link>` is added dynamically? So not when you put it there in the source? That's odd.